# Determine whether the given points are interior point of the given set

Tags: general-topology

Let $B = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 \mid -1 \le x \lt 2, 0 \lt y \le 2 \} 
\cup \{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 \mid 5 \lt x \le 7, y = 1 \}$. Determine whether a point $(0,1)$
is an interior point of $B$.

I got a little bit confuse here, since a point $(0,1)$ exactly lies on vertical line $y=1$, in which it does mean that $(0,1)$ be an interior point of not.

Here's my attempt:

Fix $0 < r = \frac{1}{2}$. Note that
\begin{equation*}
B((0,1), \frac{1}{2}) = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R} \mid x^2 + (y-1)^2 < \frac{1}{4} \}.
\end{equation*}
Let $(x,y) \in B((0,1), \frac{1}{4})$. Then,
\begin{align*}
x^2 + (y-1)^2 < \frac{1}{4} \\
x^2 < \frac{1}{4} \wedge (y-1)^2 < \frac{1}{4} \\
-\frac{1}{2} < x < \frac{1}{2} \wedge -\frac{1}{2} < y-1 < \frac{1}{2} \\
-\frac{1}{2} < x < \frac{1}{2} \wedge \frac{1}{2} < y < \frac{3}{2}.
\end{align*}

Hence, $x \in (-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) \subseteq [-1,2)$ and $y \in (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2})
\subseteq (0,2]$. Thus, forall $(x,y) \in B((0,1), \frac{1}{2})$, we have $(x,y) \in B$.
In another words, $B((0,1), \frac{1}{2}) \subseteq B$. Therefore, there exists $r>0$
such that $B((0,1), \frac{1}{2}) \subseteq B$. Hence, $(0,1)$ is an interior point of $B$.

Am I true? If not, any explain how to show it?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What about a point $(6,1)$?

Comment: $(6,1)$ is not an interior point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is fine, but verbose. You could  also note that $U=(-1,2) \times (0,2)$ is open (open rectangle) and a subset of $B$ so that any point of $U$ is an interior point of $B$, including $(0,1)$.

Comment: Nice considering. Thanks sir! What about a point $(0,2)$ sir? That's not an interior point right? Since it lies on the line $y=2$.

Comment: @user795084 it’s not indeed, as every ball around it contains points with $y>2$ which lie outside of $B$.

Comment: Great got it right now. Thanks again!

Comment: @user795084 you’re welcome. I think $U$ is exactly the set of interior points of $B$.

Comment: Wait, if $U$ is such that, how about a point $(6,1)$? It's not an interior point?

Comment: *since $(6,1)$ is in $B$

Comment: @user795084 no at $(6,1)$ we also have points outside of $B$ in every ball. It’s a boundary point.

Comment: @user795084 yes it is in $B$ but not all points of $B$ are interior points !

Comment: what example that we also have points outside of B in every ball?

Comment: @user795084 $(6,1)$ itself obviously and also some $(6-r,1)$ points as well.

Comment: what about I take $(6,1+r)$ ?

Comment: @user795084 those lie outside $B$. Mind the definition of $B$.

Comment: Okay noted now.